# React Native - converting SVG file to code

Tags: javascript, react-native, urlfetch

I would like to get SVG image code after fetching from URL.  I was trying something like this:

```
getImgXml = async () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/media/images/Activity/person-walking.svg'
    const xml = await (await fetch(url)).text()
    console.log('print xml...', xml)
  }
```

I found this example here: https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/1317#issuecomment-861498269, but it is not working for me. In console I got: `Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` and `print xml... [object Blob]`. I want to get code to modify colors later. Can somebody give mi advice how to do it properly?

Comment: Why dont you use like that ? https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri

Comment: Im using react-native-svg library, but there is a problem with color changing. Thats why before I display svg using this library I want to get code and replace `fill` attributes

Comment: I tried this way without any issue. https://snack.expo.io/@nazrdogan/anxious-beef-jerky